require js is not supporting optional chaining at the bundling process (grunt bundler)
Running "requirejs:desktop" (requirejs) task
    Error: Parse error using esprima for file:
    C:/projects/GitProjects/vendorgames-sonarqube/ndcasinocommon/base_common/fcga
mes/vendorgames/utilities/utils.js
    Error: Line 17: Unexpected token .
    In module tree:
       desktop/init
           controller
               lobbyService
Warning: RequireJS failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

This error showing in CMD, on using JavaScript optional chaining in one of the files of bundler, require js is breaking the bundling process with grunt build command
"use strict";

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var buildVersion = grunt.option('buildVersion') || '1.0';
  var currentVersion = grunt.option('currentVersion') || '1.0';

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),
    buildVersion: buildVersion,
    currentVersion: currentVersion,
    requirejs: {
      desktop: {
        options: {
          uglify2: {
            mangle: false
          },
          baseUrl: "./",
          mainConfigFile: "desktop/init.js",
          name: "desktop/init",
          out: "desktop/___FilesToBeCached___desktop.min.js",
          optimize: "none"
        }
      }
    },
    replace: {
      desktopReplace: {
        src: ["./Controller.html"],
        dest: "./",
        replacements: [{
          from: "desktop-min-<%=currentVersion%>",
          to: "desktop-min-<%=buildVersion%>"
        }]
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      desktop_build: {
        files: {
          "desktop/build.js": ["desktop/*.js", "desktop/**/*.js", "utilities/*.js"]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-requirejs");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-text-replace");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.file.setBase("../");
  grunt.registerTask("desktop", ["requirejs:desktop"]);
  grunt.registerTask("desktopReplace", ["replace:desktopReplace"]);
  grunt.registerTask("build", ["desktop", "desktopReplace"]);
};

this is the require js for the desktop code where bundling is happening
require.config({
    baseUrl: "./",
    paths: {
        utils: "utilities/utils",
    },
    shim: {
        jqueryUI: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        jqueryTouch: {
            deps: ['jqueryUI']
        }
    }
});

In this file I am using optional chaining, here is that function
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document?.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

I am using grunt bundler
If the file involved in the minified file, then facing this issue.
I want to make the build successfully bundling all the files with using es6 optional chaining features
I am using grunt bundler and require js to import and export files

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

I have removed images and changed to code

Just use code blocks, not code+quotation.

i cant able to modify more than this. can you please help me in resolving this issue

No, I can't. I know almost nothing about requireJS.

Just... don't use optional chaining? Check for null/undefined in the path as you go? It's not that hard: var ca = document ? document.cookie.split(";"); : ''; You don't use null coalescing (??) there, so I improved the existing code a bit by making ca an empty string if document didn't return anything...

no, i want to use optional chaining and build should happen successfully.
